# Is this parenthesis-free C preprocessor definition safe?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In my `/usr/include` directory, there are at least two variants of `#define NULL 0` tailored for C++ code<sup>1</sup>:

```
#define NULL 0    // from rpc/types.h
#define NULL (0)  // from libio.h
```

I feel like there must be a counter-example where the first one would not be safe, but I was not able to produce it.

Otherwise, is there some compelling argument about why it would be safe to not include the parentheses in this case (e.g., an informal "proof of correctness")?

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, without including the variant `#define NULL ((void*)0)`, which is useful for **C** but invalid in C++.

Comment: In C++ you should use `nullptr` anyway.

Comment: `#define NULL (void*)0` is not a valid definition of `NULL` in C++.

Comment: Your last example *does* have brackets in MSVC as `#define NULL ((void*)0)` which is the definition for C code.

Comment: *"...where the first one would not be safe"* - I worry more about the `(0)` substituion... allows some weird code like `myfunc NULL` to call `myfunc(0)`.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the question to correct the C-only definition of NULL.

Comment: @TonyD Interesting observation! The parentheses can actually change the semantics in unexpected ways if they appear in other contexts than expressions. (Any other than function calls or -definitions?)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I noticed Mints97's comment on unwind's answer added `if NULL`... clearly [`do`] `while NULL`'s an issue too. Pretty wild! I can imagine a newbie trying `int* p = new NULL int;` and getting an [unexpected placement new](http://ideone.com/jDMOEg) at address 0, but then they're probably as likely to add the brackets themselves ;-).

Comment: @TonyD I don't think that objection is valid since we always use things like `#define FOUR (2+2)` in order to avoid probblems with `3*FOOR` and which have always allowed weird code like `myfunc FOUR`.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: not saying it's "valid" as an "objection" - just listing differences - and anyway for the FOUR example at least you're trading the chance of these *very* minor issues for a solution to a major and pressing issue... with NULL there's no practical upside to wrapping it in parenthesis that anyone here's thought of yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no difference. The only operators with higher priority are `::`, `++` and `--` and they are not applicable on `0` nor `(0)`.

The only funny difference I see is obfuscation :

```
#define NULL (0)

void f(int x)
{
  // Do something with x
}

int main()
{
  f NULL; // This code compiles
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I believe the latter can have appeared due to [cargo-culting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), i.e. the rule/reflex to always put preprocessor definitions in parentheses for good measure.

Comment: They *can* have different interpretations. One can work with `if NULL` and the other can't =)

Comment: @Mints97 True .. that doesn't "look" like valid code but becomes so due to the parentheses in the macro, which is of course horrible but still an actual difference. Answer edited.

Comment: Agreed, except that it's not mild. Far too much code these days has redundant parentheses, apparently because whoever wrote it didn't know the language well enough to write clearly.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Even if parentheses don't happen to be necessary, their omission may compel those who examine the code in future to expend more effort determining that they are *genuinely* unnecessary than would have been necessary to simply look inside the redundant parentheses.

Comment: @supercat - `(((a*b)+(c*d))-(e*f))` compels me to sort out what those lousy infernal stupid parentheses mean. If I wanted to do that I'd program in LISP. While it's true that redundant parentheses are occasionally helpful, in many of the code examples I've seen on stack overflow they are just clutter.

Comment: @PeteBecker: In that particular example, I'd generally agree with you, unless the purpose was to particularly describe an order of operation.  Around macros and their arguments, though, I think redundancy is often a good thing; though extending it to literals may be going a bit far, in cases where macros have a mixture of positive and negative constants, especially if some positive values may need to be changed to negative values, extra parentheses around even the positive literals may lead to a more uniform appearance, and ensure that negative three gets written as `(-3)` rather than `-3`.

Answer (score 8):

If we're talking about safety, one could argue that `#define NULL 0` is actually safer than `#define NULL (0)`.

You see, the latter enables you to do something like this: `a = func NULL;` instead of `a = func(0);` which can create an uncontrolled nuclear reaction in the brain of anyone who sees that in production C code. That is quite un-safe, you know =)

Answer (score 6):

Since nobody has yet spelled it out explicitly...

> is there some compelling argument about why it would be safe to not include the parentheses in this case (e.g., an informal "proof of correctness")?

Parentheses are a grouping construct. They take an *expression* and turn it into a *primary-expression* (to use the names from the standard's grammar). A complete *primary-expression* cannot be "reached into" and split up by an operator applied to it, regardless of that operator's precedence. Aside from the issue mentioned in the comments with function calls and `if`, this is all they do; they are used in macros to ensure that the expanded result has the same precedence as it appears to have in the source (a constant looks like an atom; a *primary-expression* is treated the same way as one in the expression structure).

The digit `0` is a syntactic atom. It is already defined as a *primary-expression* by virtue of being a literal constant. There is no internal structure to the expression for an operator to split up, and the question of precedence doesn't even apply. Since there is no precedence for the parentheses to change, wrapping it in them converts the *primary-expression* into another *primary-expression*, i.e. it does literally nothing.

Reference: [C11 6.5.1 "Primary expressions"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=96), [C++11 5.1.1 "Primary expressions"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf#page=103).

Comment: "wrapping it in them (parentheses) converts the primary-expression into another primary-expression" is true when the `(` is not previously consumed by the compiler as in function call.  In function call case, `(0)` becomes a valid parenthesized  _( identifier-list )_ and not a simple primary-expression.  Thus `#define NULL (0) sqrt NULL ;` compiles.

Comment: @chux sure, but that's a) an answer from the opposite perspective ("why this doesn't help" vs. "why this hurts"); and b) more than adequately covered above. This is just the "proof" OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe, at least in terms of no unexpected operator precedence consequences.

Any macro definition that's just a plain literal with no operators is always safe. eg...

```
#define FOO 1
#define NAME "Fred"
#define malloc my_malloc
```

Comment: I don't think string literal concatenation works when literals are enclosed in parentheses.  If for whatever reason one wished to prevent a string literal from being concatenated into a larger string constant, I think adding parentheses around it would do that.